# tcpdump ip range

Tags: debian, tcpdump, filter, netfilter, nfsen

I'm using nfsen and I need to apply a filter to get specific ip range and I can't find the syntax. I searched in the doc of nfdump and tcpdump but nothing.

For now the netflows captured provides from multiples address and the ip range I want to get (and only those address) is from 130.190.0.0 to 130.190.127.255 with a mask /17

Or another way to explain this, I only want adress that start by 130.190 I don't care about other like 216.58, 51.254...etc there are a lot more

Comment: Did you mean 130.190.0.0 to 130.190.127.255? That would be the /17 block.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes that's right, the /17 is the mask of my network

Comment: What is the range you are wanting to capture? By the way your question is worded it looks to me like all of 130.190.0.0/17 (why is your range so big, by the way?)

Comment: I want to capture all the flows which concerns ip address starting by 130.190.X.X this is what I want. The problem is when I enter `net 130.190.0.0/17` as filter, it still captures adress like  216.58.198.46 but I don't want them

Comment: You may want to specify `src net` or `dst net` as appropriate.

Comment: @FerencWágner This don't solve my problem, if you want another way to explain what I want, I want to capture all the flows that concerns ip address starting by 130.190.

Comment: net is great for ip ranges that align with CIDR subnet boundaries.  what about random range numbers.  I want to sniff all traffic from the four hosts .6 through .9 in 10.4.20.6-9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a filter to capture on packets mathing 130.190.0.0/17:

```
tcpdump net 130.190.0.0/17
```

Comment: yeah already tried this but this filter capture other ip address like 216.58.198.46 and I don't know why

Comment: It will capture 216.58.198.46 if the other end (ie. source or destination) is in 130.190.0.0/17.  If you want to only catch packets where the source and destination are in 130.190.0.0/17:  `tcpdump src net 130.190.0.0/17 and dst net 130.190.0.0/17`

Comment: @slass100 thanks for responding I tried the command you gave me and I only get 2 flows ? Could you explain me why please ?    `2017-05-17 23:34:58.547     0.000 any      130.190.64.115        1(100.0)        1(100.0)     1028(100.0)        0        0  1028`
`2017-05-17 23:34:58.547     0.000 any      130.190.65.254        1(100.0)        1(100.0)     1028(100.0)        0        0  1028`

Comment: Without a diagram of your network, I can only guess.  If your system running nfsen is connected to a switch (vs. a hub or span port) it will only "see" packets to or from your system (not packets between 2 hosts connected to the same switch as your device).

Comment: Hm I guess you don't understand because my english is poor sorry about that but no matters if my machine is connected to a switch or a hub no ? I just want a filter that display machine which has their IP starting byt 130.190 from source or destination. I don't know, maybe I'm looking for something doesn't exist, maybe just no filter who does what I want